# C++ char array declaration in Class

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, char

I'm creating a game where I want to save the screen data in 1D array of data type char. Screen data has to be a global variable in the class. The size of array will be determined after initialization. In constructor there will be declared some constant values, that are used the calculate the exact size of array.

```
class Screen
{
public:
    Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height);
private:
    const uint16_t WIDTH;
    const uint16_t HEIGHT;

    char field[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
};

Screen::Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
   : WIDTH(width),
    HEIGHT(height)
{
 
}
```

This shows an error because WIDTH and HEIGHT are nonstatic members of the class. If I add keyword static before const in each declaration of dimensions (WIDTH, HEIGHT), it shows other error, saying it cannot be used as constant value. So, how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array sizes must be compile time constants. Use a vector instead.

```
#include <vector>

class Screen
{
public:
    Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height);
private:
    uint16_t WIDTH;
    uint16_t HEIGHT;

    std::vector<char> field;
};

Screen::Screen(uint16_t width, uint16_t height)
   : WIDTH(width), HEIGHT(height), field(width*height)
{ 
}
```